# Load model into $this scope

Tags: php, codeigniter, this

I'm doing a learning exercise where I'm building a pretty basic MVC framework. I'm really only doing this to learn more about OOP and it's pros, cons and common pitfalls.

I'm trying to replicate a behaviour, or syntax might be more correct, similar to the very popular framework codeigniter.

That is, I want to manually be able to load a Model from inside my Controller.

Here's how I want to perform it, and subsequently use it.

```
    $this->load->model("mymodel");
    $this->mymodel->some_function();
```

I have my loader working, it tries to run the class and this is how the load->model code looks like

```
public function model($model)
{
    if(file_exists(APPLICATION.'models/'.$model.'.php'))
    {
        include(APPLICATION.'models/'.$model.'.php');
        $this->{$model} = new $model;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I get a error running this code saying that the class $model (this should be transformed into mymodel in this case) doesn't exist.

How do I make it so that $model translates into mymodel so the code would perform a action as such: new mymodel;

Thanks for any help, I'm quite the novice in OOP so I might have gotten confused here but really cannot seem to figure this out :/

`$this->{$model}` does, however, translate into `$this->mymodel`.

**Instead of creating a new thread, I'll add to this.**

My next issue has already arisen, since it's basically a followup problem I'll add it here too.

```
$this->mymodel->some_function() returns the following error;
Notice: Undefined property: Home::$mymodel in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\home.php on line 16
```

This error shows when running `$this->mymodel->some_function();`

Home is the loaded controller.

Hultin

Comment: Looks nice actually and like it ought to work. But is the right file actually loaded? Remove the `file_exists` check or add a `else` notice. Does `APPLICATION` contain a trailing slash for instance?

Comment: Ah, there it was. the missing trailing slash. I feel really and properly stupid now. Thanks for pointing that out, however!

Comment: Why do not using autoloading?

Comment: I do not wish to autoload all models, say you'd have a large website with 100s of models, I see no reason to autoload all of them in that case. 

However, if there's something I've overlooked I'd love it if you could elaborate.

Comment: I am, as I stated previously, deliberatly taking water above my head as I've found that the best way to learn things. 

I had, as you pointed out, missunderstood how autoloading worked and I did ask to have that pointed out.

Now, I cannot see why you'd ever feel the need to call me ignorant and dumb.

What I choose to do is my buisness not yours. If you're gonna be offensive you could always go elsewhere, I didn't ask for your opinion on WHAT I am doing as a project, but what I was doing "wrong"/incorrect. Flagged your post, hope you get banished.

Comment: you could take a look at the codeigniter loader class

Comment: I usually get this error when I mess write CI_Model or the php file name.